# Kendo UI - SubGrid Inside pop up editor Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working with an MVC4 KendoUI project C# with Razor engine. 
After searching a lot on the web i could not find a way to achieve this:

I have a Kendo grid based on my model that is a Collection of "Satelite" objects wich has some properties, one of its property is a List of "Transponder" object.

I have CRUD for my "Satelite" view that consist in an editable Kendo grid, this grid does not show all the fields, i want that behaviour in editable mode where you can edit and update all its properties so i came up with an editor template, then when the user click the "Edit" button I display a custom partial view with all the fields to update. This is working well for me except when i create another grid for the "Transponder" list wich doesn't seem to work properly. I was able to load the grid  performing succesfully the read action but when i click for example the "delete" button inside the "transponder" grid, the item dissapear from the grid but doesn't go to the controller and does nothing on server side. If I update and edit again, the item is still there.

I would also like to know if you guys think that i'm doing the right approach or if you know a more straightforward way to do it.

The most similar scenario i have found it's this [Example](http://jsbin.com/IvOvUje/3/edit).

It is not exactly but i want but to give you an idea of what i pretend to reach.

**Here is the "Satelite" CRUD view:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Test_MVC_DTV.Models.Satelite>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Satelites";
}

<style>
        #organizer { 
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    .k-edit-form-container { width: auto; height: auto;}
    </style>


<div id="organizer">
        @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
            .Name("panelbar")
            .ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Multiple)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-width: 800px; width: auto;margin: auto;" })
            .Items(panelbar =>
                {
                    panelbar.Add()
                            .Text("Satélites")
                            .Expanded(true)

                            .Content(@<div style="padding: 10px;">
                                          <section>
                                              Nombre: <input style="margin-left: 7px" id="txtNombre"/> 
                                              <button style="margin-left: 10px" class="k-button" id="btnBuscar">BUSCAR</button>

                                          </section>
                                      </div>);

                })

        ) 
    </div>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
      .Name("grdSatelites")
      .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(p => p.SateliteId).Groupable(false);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Denominacion);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Comentario);

              columns.Command(cmd =>
                  {
                      cmd.Edit().Text("Editar").CancelText("Cancelar").UpdateText("Actualzar");
                      cmd.Destroy().Text("Eliminar");

                  })
                .HtmlAttributes(new {style="text-align:center;"})
                .Width(210);

          })
        .Editable(editable =>
          {
              editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).Window(wdw=>wdw.Title("Editor Satelite"));
              editable.TemplateName("SatelitesEditor");

          })
      .Events(e=>e.Edit("OnEdit"))
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()      
      .Scrollable()
      .Filterable()
      .Selectable()
      .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Agregar") )

      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource 
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .PageSize(5)
                                    .ServerOperation(false)
                                    .Model(model =>
                                    {
                                        model.Id(p => p.SateliteId);
                                        model.Field(p => p.SateliteId).Editable(false);
                                    })
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("Satelites_Read", "Home").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
                                    .Create(create => create.Action("Satelites_Create", "Home"))
                                    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Satelites_Delete", "Home"))
                                    .Update(update => update.Action("Satelites_Update", "Home"))
      )

    )

<script>

    $(function () {

        $("#btnBuscar").click(function () {
            var $filter = new Array();
            var $nombre = $("#txtNombre").val();
            if ($nombre) {
                $filter.push({ field: "Nombre", operator: "contains", value: $nombre });
            }
            var grid = $("#kendoGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.dataSource.filter($filter);
        });
    });

    function OnEdit(e) {
        $('#grdTransponders').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.read({ SateliteId: e.model.SateliteId });

    }
</script>
```

**Here is the Editor Template:**

```
@model Test_MVC_DTV.Models.Satelite

<div style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px">
            @Html.Label("Denominación:")
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Denominacion )

            @Html.Label("Ubicacion Orbital:")
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UbicacionOrbital )

            @Html.Label("Comentario:")
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Comentario )



    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Transponders)
            .Name("grdTransponders")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.TransponderID).Groupable(false);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Polaridad);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Haz);
                columns.Bound(p => p.UsuarioAsignado);
                columns.Bound(p => p.color);
                columns.Command(cmd =>
                {
                    cmd.Edit().Text("Editar").UpdateText("Actualizar").CancelText("Cancelar");
                    cmd.Destroy().Text("Eliminar");

                })
                         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" })
                         .Width(210);

            })
            .Editable(editable => {
                                      editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp);
                                      editable.TemplateName("TranspondersEditor");
            })

            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Agregar") )
            .AutoBind(false)
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(5)
                .ServerOperation(false)               
                .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(p => p.TransponderID);
                        model.Field(p => p.TransponderID).Editable(false);
                    })
                .Read(read => read.Action("Transponders_Read", "Home").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
                .Create(create => create.Action("Transponders_Create", "Home"))
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Transponders_Delete", "Home"))
                .Update(update => update.Action("Transponders_Update", "Home"))
            )
            .Pageable()

    )
    </div>
```

**My Controller For Satelite and Transponder Actions**

```
region Transponders

        public ActionResult ABMTrandpondersParaSatelite(int? SateliteId)
        {
            return View(listaSatelites.Single(x => x.SateliteId == SateliteId));
        }


        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Transponders_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int SateliteId)
        {

            return Json(listaSatelites.Single(x=>x.SateliteId==SateliteId).Transponders.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Transponders_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Transponder transponder, int IdSatelite)
        {
            if (transponder != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // var satelites = (List<Satelite>)GetSatelites();
                var satelite = listaSatelites.Single(o => o.SateliteId == IdSatelite);
                var transponderTarget = satelite.Transponders.Single(o => o.TransponderID == transponder.TransponderID);

                if (transponderTarget != null)
                {
                    int targetIndex = satelite.Transponders.IndexOf(transponderTarget);
                    satelite.Transponders[targetIndex].TransponderID = transponder.TransponderID;
                    satelite.Transponders[targetIndex].Polaridad = transponder.Polaridad;
                    satelite.Transponders[targetIndex].Haz = transponder.Haz;
                    satelite.Transponders[targetIndex].UsuarioAsignado = transponder.UsuarioAsignado;
                    satelite.Transponders[targetIndex].NumeroTranslacionIRD = transponder.NumeroTranslacionIRD;
                    satelite.Transponders[targetIndex].Comentario = transponder.Comentario;
                    satelite.Transponders[targetIndex].FrecuenciaBajada = transponder.FrecuenciaBajada;
                    satelite.Transponders[targetIndex].FrecuenciaSubida = transponder.FrecuenciaSubida;
                    satelite.Transponders[targetIndex].FrecuenciaBandaL = transponder.FrecuenciaBandaL;
                    satelite.Transponders[targetIndex].numeroXPSatelite = transponder.numeroXPSatelite;
                    satelite.Transponders[targetIndex].color = transponder.color;
                }
            }

            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Transponders_Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Transponder transponder, int IdSatelite)
        {
            if (transponder != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var satelite = listaSatelites.Single(o => o.SateliteId == IdSatelite);
                var transponderTarget = satelite.Transponders.Single(o => o.TransponderID == transponder.TransponderID);

                if (transponderTarget != null)
                {
                    satelite.Transponders.Remove(transponderTarget);
                }
            }

            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }



endregion Trandsponder

region Satelites

        public static List<Transponder> listaTransponders = (List<Transponder>)Builder<Transponder>.CreateListOfSize(6).All().Build();


        public static List<Satelite> listaSatelites = (List<Satelite>) Builder<Satelite>
                                    .CreateListOfSize(13)
                                    .All()
                                    .With(x => x.Transponders = listaTransponders)
                                    .Build();

        public ActionResult Satelites() 
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Satélites";
            return View(GetSatelites());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Satelites_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(listaSatelites.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Satelite> GetSatelites()
        {
            return listaSatelites;
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Satelites_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Satelite satelite)
        {
            if (satelite != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               // var satelites = (List<Satelite>)GetSatelites();
                var target = listaSatelites.Where(o => o.SateliteId == satelite.SateliteId).FirstOrDefault();

                if (target != null)
                {
                    int targetIndex = listaSatelites.IndexOf(target);
                    listaSatelites[targetIndex].SateliteId = satelite.SateliteId;
                    listaSatelites[targetIndex].Denominacion = satelite.Denominacion;
                    listaSatelites[targetIndex].Comentario = satelite.Comentario;
                }
            }

            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Satelites_Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Satelite satelite)
        {
            if (satelite != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // var satelites = (List<Satelite>)GetSatelites();
                var target = listaSatelites.Where(o => o.SateliteId == satelite.SateliteId).FirstOrDefault();

                if (target != null)
                {
                    listaSatelites.Remove(target);
                }
            }

            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Satelites_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Satelite satelite)
        {
            if (satelite != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                satelite.SateliteId = listaSatelites.Max(z => z.SateliteId) + 1;
                listaSatelites.Add(satelite);
            }
            return Json(new[] { satelite }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        endregion //satelites
```

**Satelite class and Transponder class**

```
 public class Satelite
    {
        public int SateliteId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Denominacion { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Comentario { get; set; }
        public double UbicacionOrbital { get; set; }
        public List<Transponder> Transponders { get; set; } 

    }
    public class Transponder
    {
        [Required]    
        public int TransponderID { get; set; }
        public Enumeradores.Polaridad Polaridad { get; set; }
        public Enumeradores.Haz Haz { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UsuarioAsignado { get; set; }
        public string NumeroTranslacionIRD { get; set; }
        public string Comentario { get; set; }
        public int FrecuenciaBajada { get; set; }
        public int FrecuenciaSubida { get; set; }
        public int FrecuenciaBandaL { get; set; }
        public int numeroXPSatelite { get; set; }
        [UIHint("Color")]
        public string color { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help would be very appreciated and thanks in advance.

*PS: Sorry for my poor english level*

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to check the following example in KendoUI CodeLibrary which demonstrate such behavior:

- [Grid Popup Editing Navigation Property Collection with nested Grid](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/grid-popup-editing-navigation-property-collection-with-nested-grid.aspx)

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work for me,I tried to do as the example and i got "Uncaught ReferenceError: kendo is not defined".
In this part of the code:
 var territoriesTemplate = kendo.template($("#territoriesTemplate").html(), { useWithBlock: false });

Comment: @JeroFranzani you might have missing something, it in fact worked for me.